# NodeJS - file download URL redirecting and retrieving html page

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, url, redirect

I have a small script that retrieves urls to download pdfs from http://gen.lib.rus.ec/. Once the url is retrieved, I have the following code to download the pdf:

```
   const download = require('download');

    const downloadFile = (url) => {
      download(url, 'dist').then(() => {
        console.log('done!');
      });
    };
```

The problem is what gets saved is a .php page with html content and not the actual pdf. The same link on the browser: sometimes redirects to a page with ads and a download link for the PDF, and at other times directly downloads the pdf.

example link:

```
http://libgen.io/get.php?md5=bb6aa2785236bbbd575f98a6a8c942fc
```

(sometimes) this redirects to:

```
http://libgen.io/ads.php?md5=bb6aa2785236bbbd575f98a6a8c942fc
```

So from the looks of it, my app seem to always retrieve the `ads.php` link although `get.php` is fed into the `downloadFile` function. I can parse the retrieved php page, find the download URL (refer below url) and download the pdf but is there a better way to directly initiate the pdf download programatically?

URL in retrieved html file that downloads the pdf:

```
http://libgen.io/get.php?md5=f49b28272e405bf000fe72e5d93c4ea0&key=MBJ0NVLFPDGELI3R
```

**edit**

get.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Library Genesis</title>

<style>
#message {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: #0f9d58;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>
<script src="/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script></head><body><script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function appendMessage(argument) {
        var div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'message').text('Ad block is installed and active. Please support us by disabling it.');
        var add = $('table').before(div);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($("ins").css('display') == "none") {
            appendMessage();
        }
    }, 500);
});
</script><table width=1000 align="center" border=0>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F5F6CE" rowspan=2><font size=2 color="grey">Advertising:</font><br><div id="ads10">
<!-- gen_sky3 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1513624324396300"
     data-ad-slot="9137517849"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div></td>
<td rowspan=2 valign="top" bgcolor="#F5F6CE"><font size=2 color="grey">BitCoin: <a href="bitcoin:1PiZNj7uhejkdMg5ycbqdGduKKafy8eubm?label=libgen">1PiZNj7uhejkdMg5ycbqdGduKKafy8eubm</a></font><br><div id="ads9">
<!-- gen_sky2 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1513624324396300"
     data-ad-slot="3422388247"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div></td>
<td align='center' rowspan=2 valign='top'><a href='http://libgen.io/get.php?md5=f49b28272e405bf000fe72e5d93c4ea0&key=ON32H85E8S3NRX3D'><h2>GET</h2></a></br><a href='/book/index.php?md5=F49B28272E405BF000FE72E5D93C4EA0&oftorrent='>Download via torrent </a><input id="textarea-example" value="John E. Jackson-The Biology of Apples and Pears (The Biology of Horticultural Crops)-Cambridge University Press (2003).pdf" type="text" size="9"><button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#textarea-example"> (need rename file)</button><script>new Clipboard(".btn-clipboard");</script></br><textarea rows='13' name='bibtext' id='bibtext' readonly cols='40'>@book{book:222949,
   title =     {The Biology of Apples and Pears (The Biology of Horticultural Crops)},
   author =    {John E. Jackson},
   publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
   isbn =      {0521380189,9780521380188,9780511067464,0511067461},
   year =      {2003},
   series =    {},
   edition =   {},
   volume =    {},
   url =       {http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=f49b28272e405bf000fe72e5d93c4ea0}}</textarea>
<br><img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fgen.lib.rus.ec%2Fbook%2Findex.php%3Fmd5%3Df49b28272e405bf000fe72e5d93c4ea0&choe=UTF-8' title='Link to Libgen' /></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"  bgcolor="#F5F6CE" rowspan=2><div id="ads18">
<!-- gen_sky_160x600_2 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1513624324396300"
     data-ad-slot="4896944640"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div></td>
</tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of a saved .php file content?

Comment: I ask because I don't really know how their system works, but I think get.php needs a key to download a file. So maybe sometimes in the background it redirects to ads.php which then just returns to get.php plus a key with no delay at all.

Comment: @fingeron updated the question with the .php file

Comment: So to me it seems that `ads.php` sometimes redirects you right away to the requested URL, but it is still the first response for the `get.php` request. If it doesn't redirect, you are given this page which contains the prepared url (meaning it is not generated AFTER the response was given, it was generated in the request process). Can you test this possibility?